# Angular 2 Injectable is missing object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

I've created a simple injectable that I'm using for mock testing until I feel like Implementing my provider to retrieve user data. It looks like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class Identity {
   public userInfo: {id: 1};
}
```

I request it in my a a component like so:

```
export class TabsPage {
    constructor(public identity: Identity) {
        console.log(this.identity.userInfo);
    }
}
```

The Identity is Injected fine but userInfo is undefined, what is going on here?  How can I pass data through my provider?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are defining a type (typescript type) for user info, not a value, thus it is `undefined`. `public userInfo = { id: 1 };` initializes its value. (notice you have a colon `:` there in your question, not a `=`.

Comment: Thanks! interesting how that even compiles.  I'm just waiting for the time limit on the question to expire I'll accept this as the answer when stack allows me

Comment: Why wouldn't it compile?

Comment: @johnny5 it compiles because the typescript object literal type you defined is valid and is locking its future value to be `{ id: 1 }` always, if you tried to assign its value to something different, keeping that type, it would error. So it compiled fine as it was never initialized to anything.

Comment: @Juan thanks for the explanation I didn't know type script allows you to define constants like that.  I'd upvote you twice if I could

Comment: yw!
 @johnny5 think of types like null or undefined, they just allow you to set those values. In this case, it is sort of like a readonly type for a mutable attribute where through typescript you lock it at compile time to a specific value. This Question and answer addresses this topic:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44560995/why-does-typescript-accept-a-value-as-a-data-type

Comment: @juan good read, do you know if you can set it to be within a range?

Comment: @johnny5 not possible at the moment. You can set it to several values with OR, like this: `attribute: 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 = 5; // it can be 1, 2, 3 or 5.` but it's ugly. You are better off validating ranges at runtime.