# operator '===' cannot be applied to types 'false' and 'true'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I know this below code is stupid. But in real time it may possible while compiling with two different data with same type.

```
if (false === true) {}// getting error
```

> operator '===' cannot be applied to types 'false' and 'true'

But `Object.is()` is accepting this different data without any error and it returning `false`

I know the [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30543190/object-is-vs) between them. But why typescript throwing syntax error as same time why `Object.is()` not throwing that error.

Also this error message is correct? or not?

*operator '===' cannot be applied to types 'false' and 'true*. it should be like `operator '===' cannot be applied to types 'Boolean' and 'Boolean'`

If the message is wrong, then it solved in any upgraded versions? I
m using typescript 2.0.3 version.

This problem is occurred in this below scenarios

- 1

  ```
  Object.is("string", "string");
  if ("string" === "string1") {
  }
  ```
- 2

  ```
  Object.is(1, 2);
  if (1 === 2) {
  }
  ```

etc..

Comment: Okay....it can't be applied...what is the question?

Comment: FYI Two string objects will never be equal to each other - even if they both contain identical characters.

Comment: Why you're suggesting that the error message you're getting for _clearly_ faulty code, is wrong, is beyond me.

Comment: @ScottMarcus: [`"a" === "a"` is `true`.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=if%20(%22a%22%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22a%22)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20document.write(%22a%20equals%20a!%22)%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: @ScottMarcus ""==="" is given true. it's not showing that message

Comment: @Cerbrus Comment updated to say "string objects". `var a = "a"; var b = "b"; a === b; // false`

Comment: @ScottMarcus: now you're comparing references, not strings.

Comment: @ScottMarcus That will creates new reference while you assign the value to a variable

Comment: @Cerbrus Yes, that was actually my point. Comment edited to clarify.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typescript is basically throwing an error there because it's bad code.

`true` will never ever equal `false`. Typescript knows this, and tells you to fix your code.

Since these are constant values, they're considered to be of the types `true` and `false`. The error message might be slightly confusing, but it's correct, while giving a bit of an insight into the Typescript engine.

You'll get a similar error for this code:

```
if (1 === 2) {}
```

Error:

> *Operator '===' cannot be applied to types '1' and '2'.*

Comparing constants like these [throws that error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=false%20%3D%3D%3D%20true%3B%0D%0A1%20%3D%3D%3D%202%3B%0D%0A%22a%22%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22b%22%3B):

```
false === true; // Operator '===' cannot be applied to types 'false' and 'true'.
    1 === 2;    // Operator '===' cannot be applied to types '1' and '2'.
  "a" === "b";  // Operator '===' cannot be applied to types '"a"' and '"b"'.
```

[`Object.is`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is) is completely different from `===`. `Object.is` performs *no* type coercion, and ***only*** compares both parameter's *value*. Since TypeScript doesn't validate those arguments with the function's functionality, it doesn't throw an error there.

Comment: yeah all of knows that but it still does not mention anything about error message

Comment: Ok, true will never be false, so this code is not very useful. Still syntactically it looks okay, it could run fine, so it's weird that it's rejected and even weirder that Typescript doesn't give a descriptive error (like "unreachable code" or "expression always evaluates to false"). You make it sound like this message and it's cause are obvious and that the code is blatantly faulty, but I'd appreciate some form of 'proof' because it doesn't at all feel obvious.

Comment: OK. fine. But what about the message? true and false is a value not a type. true&false is a type of Boolean.

Comment: `True` and `False` are actually of type `Boolean`

Comment: @Neoares: For TypeScript, `true` and `false` can be types on their own.

Comment: @Cerbrus Then, since `1` and `2` are constant values, they're also considered to be of types `1` and `2` and you can not compare them?

Comment: @Neoares: [Correct.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=if%20(false%20%3D%3D%3D%20true)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aif%20(1%20%3D%3D%3D%202)%20%7B%20%7D)

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have correctly declare your boolean variable , I think you have declared it to false/true instead of Boolean.
I hope this could help someone.

Comment: No, Typescript allow value as type Please check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44560995/why-does-typescript-accept-value-as-a-data-type