# Wrong "Operator '!==' cannot be applied to types 'false' and 'true'." error?

Tags: typescript

Why is it not allowed to check for a changed value of a property?

```
public static enumerateDescendants(ancestor: Node,
    cb: (node: Node, settings: { stopContinueVertical: boolean }) => any): void {
    const settings: { stopContinueVertical: boolean } = { stopContinueVertical: false };

    MyClass.enumerateChildren(
        ancestor, (node) => {
            settings.stopContinueVertical = false;
            cb(node, settings);

            if (settings.stopContinueVertical as any !== true) /*!! Here as any is required*/{
                MyClass.enumerateDescendants(node, cb);
            }
        }
    );
}

public static doWork(): void {
    MyClass.enumerateDescendants(
        MyClass.getCurrentNode(), (node, settings) => {
            /*Do some work*/
            settings.stopContinueVertical = true; /*!! Here the value is changed*/
        }
    );
}
```

If I don't use `as any` I get `(TS) Operator '!==' cannot be applied to types 'false' and 'true'.`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48523692/operator-cannot-be-applied-to-types-false-and-true

Comment: @misorude Probably not, in the other post there is a progamming error. In this post stopContinueVertical can actually change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[To quote one of the TypeScript developers, on the topic of the compiler's control flow analysis:](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998)

> The primary question is: When a function is invoked, what should we assume its side effects are?
>
> One option is to be pessimistic and reset all narrowings, assuming that any function might mutate any object it could possibly get its hands on. Another option is to be optimistic and assume the function doesn't modify any state. Both of these seem to be bad.

The current implementation leans further towards the latter option, and this is what's causing your issue - the compiler is unable to track the fact that `MyClass.enumerateDescendants` mutates `settings`, and therefore it thinks you're performing a comparison on a value that never changes!

Unfortunately, there's not really any way around this other than the sort of workarounds you've already tried for now. The relevant issue on the TypeScript repo is [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998) - it's an interesting read.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the error in details:

[image]

> [ts] This condition will always return 'true' since the types 'false' and 'true' have no overlap.
>   (property) stopContinueVertical: false

so since it is set to a const `false` above it know that this `if` is totally redundant and throws an error for this reason.

Comment: It's not constant

Comment: `const settings: { stopContinueVertical: boolean } = { stopContinueVertical: false };`

Comment: An object assigned to a const variable doesn't magically make all of its properties const

Comment: you are right. apperently typescript predicts that it is not changed anywhere else, eventhough it can be modified via the callback `cb`. So apparently you found a bug in TypeScript - please go to https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues and report the issue

Comment: OK thanks, I'm gonna try updating to 3.1.1 first before filing an issue. Maybe it's fixed.