# boolean comparison generates TS2365 error

Tags: typescript

The code below gets `TS2365: Operator '===' cannot be applied to types 'false' and 'true'.` error on `if (b === true)`.

```
let b = false;
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
arr.forEach(val => {
    if (val < 3) {
        b = true;
    }
});
if (b === true) { // generates TS2365 error

}
```

I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48523692/operator-cannot-be-applied-to-types-false-and-true) and I understand Typescript generates this error if the condition never satisfied.

But the condition will be satisfied because the `arr` has values less than 3.

Why I got this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limitation of the way typescript does flow analysis to determine the assignment of `b`. Such analysis does not cross function bounties. See [this discussion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998).

A simple solution would be to use a type assertion when assigning `b`.

```
let b = false as boolean;
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
arr.forEach(val => {
    if (val < 3) {
        b = true;
    }
});
if (b === true) { // ok

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting it in simple language, the following code section

```
b===true
```

is always false, because TypeScript Engine did not interpreted b as boolean, until and unless you explicitly specifies it, because === operator check for the equality of operands' types as well.

so i according to me, the following code should also work:

```
b == true
```

as it automatically performs type conversion of operands.